# Using Samsung S-Pen in Canvas

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas

I am working on a web application where the user should be abled to sign a document on a tablet. We use the Galaxy Tab 12.2 because the S-Pen has the desired precision. 
The canvas where i draw on uses listens to the `touch` events to draw on the canvas.

```
        canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', handleStart);
        canvas.addEventListener('touchmove' , handleMove);
```

The problem here is, that if the user touches the canvas with his fingers, the canvas will draw lines there.

Is there a way to differentiate between S-Pen events and 'normal' touch events?

I know that on the Surface Pro 3 with Internet Expoler I can handle Pen input different from finger input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so i found a solution myself that is working pretty well. 
The SPen fires an `ontouch` event with `radiusX` and `radiusY` = 0.

The events that are triggered with a finger always have a radius > 0. So all that was to do is add

```
if(e.targetTouches[0].radiusX === 0)
```

into the event handlers to draw on my canvas.

Check out this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chillichief/3nh10pLp/)

Answer (score 2):

The S-Pen should fire an `onMouseOver` event when it gets close to the screen (depending on browser & S-Pen version), you can take advantage of that by storing a global variable `isSPen = false` and having a global `onMouseOver` event setting that variable to `true`. Try different browsers and see which ones will deliver the event, usually the stock browser always works best.

If that doesn't work, you may need to host your webpage inside an app container; Android has an `OnHoverListener` that picks up the S-Pen. You can use a full-screen WebView and communicate to it with Android's JavaScript messaging API: [Example](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html)

Hope I helped you out, good luck

Comment: Using the `mouseOver` event is a pretty clever idea. I'm not sure how reliable this solution is. I found another way and i will post it as an answer, if you want to check it out

Answer (score -1):

The pointerType property can be accessed through the 'pointerdown' event instead of relying on the 'mousedown' event.